# Semantic HTML: where to place my form buttons?

Tags: html, forms

Consider the next form:

```
<form>
    <h2>Form</h2>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Simple list with Create/Delete</legend>

        [...]

        <footer>
            <button>Add</button>
            <button>Remove</button>
            <button>Remove all</button>
        </footer>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Single input</legend>

        <input type="file" />

        <footer>
            <button>Save as PDF</button>
            <button>Save as XLS</button>
            <button>Save as SVG</button>
        </footer>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dynamic wizard</legend>

        [...]

        <footer>
            <button>Next</button>
        </footer>
    </fieldset>

    [...]

    <footer>
        <button>Reset</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>
        <button>Save</button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

I feel comfortable with the idea of using `<footer>` inside a `<form>` or a `<fieldset>`, but im not sure if it's correct, it looks a bit saturated with footers

I could use `<div>` instead of `<footer>` but it feels "semantically poor", and `<menu>` feels awkward when using a single button.

Maybe the solution is to place them directly under `<form>` or `<fieldset>`.

```
<form>
    <h2>Form</h2>

    [...]

    <button>Reset</button>
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

¿What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can place your form fields and buttons in separate `section` blocks.

```
<form>
    <section class="fields">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Simple list with Create/Delete</legend>
            ...
        </fieldset>
    </section>
    <section class="fields">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Single input</legend>
            ...
        </fieldset>
    </section>
    <section class="buttons">
        <button type="button">Reset</button>
        <button type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </section>
</form>
```

Comment: I really don't like sections without a header or a heading tag: it doesn't feel semantically correct: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section. Also, fieldset is already a sectioning element, I don't see what's the use of nesting them into a section.

Comment: w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section: "The section element is NOT a generic container element. The section element is appropriate only if the contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline". section would  be acceptable if multiple fieldset were nested, yes :)

Comment: @Gabriel `section`s are just containers wherein you can group elements with the same theme.  `section`s are typically with headings but that doesn't mean that it's wrong or not semantic to omit them.`fieldset`s on the other hand house a set of form controls. You can have a `section` of addresses that contains a number of `fieldsets` that have different legends like Present Address, Permanent Address, Business Address, etc.